# Heroku, There's nothing here, yet. after adding custom domain

Tags: heroku

I deployed my app to Heroku, works fine with the generated URL, however after adding a custom domain and setting the CNAME on Namecheap to the one provided by Heroku, I get 'There's nothing here, yet.'

Answer (score 16):

Did you add the 'www.' when adding the custom domains in Heroku?

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53093756

Answer (score 11):

`***.herokudns.com` endpoints are not directly browsable, and are only to be used as CNAME targets for DNS. Be sure to check your app status by browsing to your custom domain and not from the url that looks like `whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com`.

From [the heroku help portal](https://help.heroku.com/3EUIOIVB/why-can-t-i-access-herokudns-com-cname-endpoints-in-my-browser)