# herokudns with custom domain: No such app

Tags: heroku, dns, namecheap

I've reviewed [Heroku's custom domain tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#view-existing-domains) several times but I can't seem to make my Heroku app work with a custom domain (hosted on namecheap.com). The problem: Herokudns doesn't resolve the app name

This is my configuration at Heroku:

[image: Heroku]

And these are my DNS records:

[image: Namecheap]

When I go to either omaiga.com.sv or www.omaiga.com Heroku responds: "No such app. There's nothing here, yet." What am I doing wrong?

Some details:

- I could use **omaiga.herokuapp.com** instead of **protected-hookworm-0tshh2aii82icypukmovp7rz.herokudns.com** but I plan to implement SSL later so I need to make it work with herokudns.
- namecheap.com [recommends](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/434/2237/how-do-i-set-up-host-records-for-a-domain) to user a 301 redirect from my root domain to my 'www' instead of using an ALIAS record in order not to affect the email records.

Comment: Are you sure that `protected-hookworm-0tshh2aii82icypukmovp7rz.herokudns.com` is the right DNS target? It doesn't look right to me. Try running `heroku domains` to make sure.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'll answer my own question: according to [Heroku's documentation](https://help.heroku.com/3EUIOIVB/why-can-t-i-access-herokudns-com-cname-endpoints-in-my-browser) the *.herokudns addresses are not browsable. Instead, Heroku uses the 'Host' header from the client to ensure the correct application responds to a request.

The problem here was that the Host header is coming with 'www' from Namecheap (since I made that my canonical name -CNAME-) but I didn't give the 'www' to Heroku so the solution is to add the custom domain in Heroku with 'www'.

Comment: You saved me, I have been struggling with this for the last two weeks. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours on this! I wish I could upvote you more than once