# django relation "accounts_user" does not exist after heroku upload

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, django-models

I upload my Django web  app to Heroku successfully and login page appears as well as expected
but when I try login I getting this error:

```
relation "accounts_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ser"."is_active", "accounts_user"."is_staff" FROM "accounts_...
```

Also I am getting this error when I try to acces `ulrs` by typing

`cursor "_django_curs_140062995079296_sync_1" does not exist`

I don't know where this error Is generating from. But I am using custom user models that I seems the error to be there

> *here is the custom user model I used*

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields) 

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField( unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    staffType = models.ForeignKey(staffType, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField( default=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'


    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate` on server?

Comment: @iliya how I can run

Comment: with command like this `heroku run python manage.py migrate` or you can login in to your project (`heroku login`) then running this `heroku run bash -a your-project-name`  and then run the command above.

Comment: @iliya thanks men you saved me. but I have other problem when I try to access web from other devices  it redirects to Heroku  page with  ` **There's nothing here,ye**

Comment: wll done. For the second problem I suggest search a little since the problem has many reasons, I searched and found two or three at least. Take a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026340/herokudns-with-custom-domain-no-such-app/53093756#53093756 ] . Also appreciate vote up right answers.